# Github Actions: is there a way to make it mandatory for pull request to merge

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using a **commitlint** Github action to verify our commit messages.  Just wanted to check if there is a way I can make it mandatory to pass before merging pull request.

**current behaviour:** 
commitlint github action fails, however, I can still merge the pull reqest

**desired behaviour** 
if commitlint github action fails, button to merge pull request should be disabled. (i.e. like reviewer restriction)

Comment: What is it doing right now? Allowing merge even when the commit message is not standard?

Comment: actions fails, but I can still merge the pull request.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add rules to your branches and how your merge request works.

Your repo -> Settings -> branches -> Branch protection rules -> Add rule

There, you will find something called `Require status checks to pass before merging`. Under this, you should see `Status checks found in the last week for this repository`. If you find the status you want to be passed before merging, you can enable the same.

Docs: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests

Comment: I am running into the same issue as OP, but unable to resolve.  I'm migrating from Azure Devops pipelines to GitHub Actions and I'm unable to select a GHA as a "gating check"/required.  The Azure Devops pipelines work as required, but none of my GHA show up when I search for status checks.  IDK if it matters, but I'm on GitHub Enterprise Cloud.

Comment: @MattM What are you searching for in the checks autocomplete field? Note that you should be searching for the job name, not the workflow name.

Comment: ugh, it took me DAYS to realize that the "status checks" thing is a search field! I expected it would simply be a list of all existing checks and you can mark the ones that are required. *sigh*

Comment: Does anyone know how to enable this for the whole workflow or all active workflows?