# Github actions to prevent anyone from PRing/merging uncompilable code

Tags: github, github-actions

The idea is to use GitHub actions to determine when a pull request is opened whether the code in the branch is compliable or not. The way you do that on your local machine is run the make command. If any errors come up (I.e. it does not return a status code of 0), there was a compilation error. GitHub should have ways to test for these kinds of errors and if they do occur, they should block the PR from being merged in.

```
name: Prevent uncompiable code

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: make command
        run: make
```

Then I would turn on "Require status checks to pass before merging" and select this workflow. Will that work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779334/13126651, check this

Comment: Welcome to SO @Arual Arora. `Will that work?` --> have you tried it yourself? :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is good. However, most of the mergers are now as follows.

Before merging, it informs you of the CI results so that the person with the merge permission can check it and merge it fluidly.

In other words, if it is a code that causes a lot of bugs to flow in, it can be rejected (Close), if it is a minor bug, in other word , it is a bug that occurs in the main code, it can be merged.